# Magento 2 Installation: css/js/images not loading

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I am trying to install Magento2(0.1.0-alpha107 ) in my localhost powered by OSX 10.10 + brew installed php-fpm + mysql + nginx.
Steps that I followed for installation:

- `mkdir /path/to/magento2 && cd /path/to/magento2`
- `git clone git@github.com:magento/magento2.git .`
- `composer install`
- `cd setup`
- `composer install`
- `php -f index.php install --base_url=http://magento2alpha.dev/ --backend_frontname=admin --db_host=localhost --db_name=magento2alpha --db_user=root --db_pass=root --admin_firstname=Raj --admin_lastname=KB --admin_email=magepsycho@gmail.com --admin_username=admin --admin_password=pass123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago`

So far everything worked great. But when you load the frontend: http://magento2alpha.dev/
it's showing plain text only (i.e. css/images/js are missing).
View source gives you the path like http://magento2alpha.dev/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/[css/images]/[css/images file] which led to the 404 page
My nginx conf file looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name magento2alpha.dev;
    root /Users/Raj/Sites/magento/magento2alpha;

    location /setup {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @setuphandler;
    }

    # Rewrite Setup's Internal Requests
    location @setuphandler {
        rewrite /setup /magento/magento2alpha/setup/index.php;
    }

    location / {
        index index.php index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    }

     # Rewrite Internal Requests
     location @handler {
        rewrite / /magento/magento2alpha/index.php;
     }

     # Rewrite magento2 static files
     #location /pub/static {
     #   rewrite ^/pub/static/(.*)$ /magento/magento2alpha/pub/static.php?resource=$1? last;
     #}

     location /pub/static {
          try_files $uri $uri/ @static;
     }

     location @static {
           rewrite ^/pub/static/(.*)$ /magento/magento2alpha/pub/static.php?resource=$1? last;
     }

     #location ~ .php/ {
     #    rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
     #}

    location ~ \.php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
        try_files $uri =404;
        expires        off;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 900s;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;

        ## Magento 2 Developer mode
        fastcgi_param MAGE_MODE "developer";
    }
}
```

I guess the issue lies in the static files rewrite. But this is what I followed from the github which is not working.
Is there any workaround?

Comment: If you want core team to respond, please ask m2 questions on github. We track them there closely. Eg we can share ngix plans, describe deploy scripts etc.

Comment: @AlanKent Yeah going to post on github issue section.

Comment: Well changing to `production` modeis the quick fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have to modify my nginx conf file to make it working as:
(REF: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/802)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name magento2alpha.dev;
    root /Users/Raj/Sites/magento/magento2alpha;

    location /setup {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @setuphandler;
    }

    # Rewrite Setup's Internal Requests
    location @setuphandler {
        rewrite /setup /setup/index.php;
    }

    location / {
        index index.php index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    }

     # Rewrite Internal Requests
     location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
     }

     location /pub/static {
          try_files $uri $uri/ @static;
     }

     location @static {
           rewrite ^/pub/static/(.*)$ /pub/static.php?resource=$1? last;
     }

     location ~ \.php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
        try_files $uri =404;
        expires        off;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 900s;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;

        ## Magento 2 Developer mode
        fastcgi_param MAGE_MODE "developer";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=256M \n max_execution_time=18000";
     }
}
```

One thing that I noticed is: If you create virtual host specific configuration in nginx's `conf.d` is more resource expensive & slower than keeping in `sites-enabled` dir.

**[Edit]**
Sorry my bad, xdebug was causing the slowness not the nginx conf.

Answer (score 2):

Any file requested within `/pub/static` that does not exist currently needs to get routed through Magento. This is currently done through `/pub/static.php`.

You can see this rewrite in `/pub/static/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
# Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
RewriteRule ^version.+?/(.+)$ $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* ../static.php?resource=$0 [L]
```

Looking at your nginx configuration you have this commented out:

```
 # Rewrite magento2 static files
 #location /pub/static {
 #   rewrite ^/pub/static/(.*)$ /magento/magento2alpha/pub/static.php?resource=$1? last;
 #}
```

Presumably making those lines executable would solve the issue, I'm not very familiar with nginx configuration but something like this *might* also work:

```
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename){ 
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /../static.php?resource=$0 last;
    }
}
```

Comment: 'Rewrite magento2 static files' is there just below it. I tried with both variations but none of them worked.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/64808/3326

When not in production mode Magento 2 will try to create symlinks for some static resources. You can change that behavior by doing the following.

Open up `app/etc/di.xml` and find the `virtualType name="developerMaterialization"` section. In that section you'll find an item `name="view_preprocessed"` that needs to be modified or deleted. You can modify it by changing the contents from `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink` to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

Delete the files under `pub/static` to get rid of any existing symlinks. You may want to be careful not to delete the `.htaccess` file.

This should solve your error with the symlink.

Answer (score 0):

this is the best answer so far

> You can modify it by changing the contents from
>   `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink` to
>   `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

Comment: css,js works but not images. Images are not loaded

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after running the Magento 2 install and found that the install failed to actually deploy the static files. I received 404 for many admin files, including bootstrap, etc. In order to fix I ran a command from the site root to force the static file deployment:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

This will regen static assets for frontend themes and adminhtml backend.