# Magento2 installation issue

Tags: admin, javascript, css, frontend, magento2-dev-beta

I have installed Magento2 on my localhost. But it doesn't load the CSS and JS files. Admin interface is as below. Frontend also have the same issue. I set the file permissions. How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: nope, nothing resolved the issue yet

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the  `pub/static` folder should work.

But also try `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` or `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` from the root folder

See [CSS and Javascript files are not loading after Magento 2 installation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64857/css-and-javascript-files-are-not-loading-after-magento-2-installation)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like UrlRewrite module is disabled in Apache configuration. Please try solution from [Magento Documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_no-styles.html)

Answer (score 0):

Allow the loading of htaccess files and usage of rewrite rules.I have same problem occur, Enabling `rewrite_module` of apache works for me.

Or try to delete the `pub/static` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Look into

**\app\etc\di.xml** and find the

**virtualType name="developerMaterialization"** .

In this you'll find an item **name="view_preprocessed"** and change its content

from

**Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink**

to

**Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy**

then delete the files under **pub/static** except .htaccess file and reload the site.

It should work for you.

Answer (score -1):

**If you are facing problem of css and js page load design after installation in magento2**

**please follow the following step-:**

open the terminal and navigate to magento web root

```
 $ cd /var/www/html/magento2
```

**Step 1.**

```
$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

**Step 2.**

```
$ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

**Step 3.**

make sure apache "rewrite_module" is enable and then restart the server

**Step 4.**

```
$ chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento2
```

**Step 5.**

```
$ chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento2
```

**Step 6.**

delete cache folder under var/cache

**The above step working. I hope this will work for you also.**