# Magento 2.0.2 js not loaded

Tags: magento2, javascript

Magento 2.0.2 giving error -Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)[image]

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64857/css-and-javascript-files-are-not-loading-after-magento-2-installation

Comment: Try this php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Already tried 4-5 times after removing pub/static/_requirejs, pub/static/frontend, pub/static/adminhtml . Also removed var/cache, var/generation and var/view_preprocessed  - but does work for me.

Answer (score -1):

i think it because wrong file permissions try `sudo chmod -R 777 app/etc/ var/ pub/static pub/media/`

Comment: It could be a file permission issue, but 777 is never a good idea. Better fix the file ownership and then use the recommended 660 for files and 770 for directories. See: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Comment: i add command that give this permissions to specified folders that magento give same permissions in developer mode