# Magento 2 file permission error

Tags: magento2

I recently installed magento2 with sample data on my server.

But i see that every **css, js** also **catalog images** permission is not readable for user..

For that i m getting so many require.js errors. Also product view page is not working..

I run `php magento setup:static-content:deploy` and the static content deployed successfully. But seeing that file permission are not readable.

What i need to do now??

Comment: `sudo chmod 777 -R //your magento folder path` run this command

Comment: I did. But not solved the problems. Please help

Comment: did you add magetno folder path? and check current folder and file permission. using window or linux

Comment: I don't get you ! can you explain??

Comment: the full command is `sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/mangeto` did you try that

Comment: On my magento root folder i run `sudo chmod 777 -R *`

Comment: Also my admin dashboard not opening

Comment: all the frontend page are working fine?

Comment: No product view page is not working

Comment: did the console showing forbidden error for file?

Comment: Console just showing require.js error

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64857/css-and-javascript-files-are-not-loading-after-magento-2-installation check this

Comment: tried bro :( !!

Comment: Which OS, server you are using?

Comment: linux server i m using

Comment: Which web server you used `apache` or  `nginx`?

Comment: apache !!!!!!!!

Comment: There might be directory/file owner permission issue, please find your server owner through `ps aux | grep apache` console command and ensure that user have `read`/`write` permission on Magento directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to give root user permission for that subdomain. and then try to deploy