# After installing magento2.0.4 version, dashboard is not working properly

Tags: admin, dashboard, magento-2.0.4

After installing Magento 2.0.4 version, it logged in properly but products, system and other options on dashboard are not accessible. When I click on product it is not responding, same with other. I am unable to find any solution for it.

Can anyone guide me on this please?

Comment: Can you cleanup browser cache and try again?

Comment: check your folder and file permission! and start deploying your files

Comment: I cleanup browser cache still same problem

Comment: my folder permission are 755  and file 644

Answer (score 1):

Go to your magento root /app/etc/di.xml line number 574 approximately and change the code

```
        <item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
```

To

```
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
```

Remove cache , try it again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I need more help my new magento version is not accepting css i think

Comment: it is displaying without css only normal text bot front end and backend dashboard

Comment: Cool, try php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy  as well as follow @sagar http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64857/css-and-javascript-files-are-not-loading-after-magento-2-installation

Comment: My rewrite module is enabled and i cleared all cache from var/cache but i don't understand how to do this  "php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy"

Comment: Hey, when i changed the permission to 755 the css worked but again the products and other options on dashboard is not working like befor. after replacing your code <item...copy> it was working but now when css worked options in backend stopped working.

Comment: You have to install or upgrade Magento 2 by composer. i think some files are missing,  try to install it again with fresh code by using composer.

Comment: Hi i am trying to install it on cpanel. so i download the latest magento from magento website and put the files in cpanel. is it not correct?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following in the command prompt:

**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

It will load necessary css and images.
Then try logging into admin. It works.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, i am using live server

Comment: I think you can run it in live server if you have the access. It will not create any impact on magento installation. If you don't have the access you can ask your network or system administrator to run the command.

Comment: To run the above command you need to have shell access. Goto Magento installation directory (say **/var/www/html/magento** , for example), then run the command.

<magento-installation-dir>~ **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

Comment: same steps for cpanel ?

Comment: Yes. But you need shell access to it