# Failed to load css and js script after successful installation

Tags: magento2, installation

I have got a hard time dealing with the Magento installation. The installation is successful but the page is showing just plain text with all css and javascript failed to load.

I am using subdomain of shop.domain.com to point to a subfolder in my root. My root domain.com is a Wordpress project and i want the shop.domain.com using the magento.

After reading through many tutorial online and so much time spent, i still fail to get this resolve. One of the answer from this link - [CSS and Javascript files are not loading after Magento 2 installation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64857/css-and-javascript-files-are-not-loading-after-magento-2-installation)

step 1. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
step 2. php bin/magento indexer:reindex
step 3. make sure apache "rewrite_module" is enable and then restart the server
step 4. delete cache folder under var/cache

I spoke to my hosting server support, and the **shocking** reply i got is:
We could not allow you to use the options. Our security policy on shared server wont allow you to do so. So I am suggesting you to upgrade your hosting to cloud VPS or Dedicated server. We are no longer encouraging the magento 2 on shared servers. We will remove the that version from softaculas soon. That version of  application require so many functions which we are blocking in shared servers due to security risk.

Do i need a dedicated server to run Magento? Could anyone help on my problem?

FYI, the hosting Server support has helped to remove the following 2 lines in the root .htaccess file. If that 2 lines are not removed, it will cast the error "Internal Server Error" on page load before Magento installation.

#

### enable rewrites

### Options +FollowSymLinks

##   RewriteEngine on

#

Answer (score 1):

Magento2 will not run on YOUR shared host. There are plenty of shared hosting providers out there who let you run those commands and configure your server for magento2 (and have the right php and mysql versions).

Comment: Is this the Magento limitation or server limitation? I was not aware that we MUST have a server which able to run those command before we can use Magento. My current site is able to function well, i am able to login to my backend but all just display as plain text. Couldn't this be fixed by changing the .htaccess only ? If Magento requires  a server that able to run command, then it should first be highlighted out as the requirement. What you think?

Comment: @bedum it is a consequence of the fact that magento2 is not stable yet and very often you need to use commands because of bugs. Maybe with 2.1 it is more stable or 2.2. What version do you have?

Comment: I am using the latest 2.1 with no sample data. I am indeed very confuse now. I bought a share server and a theme and get ready to explore this excitement but was told the server is not fit. If this is a case, then i would think this is Magento limitation as they should have list down the rquirement that your server must be able to run the php command

Comment: @bedum You can always install it locally on your computer, do everything you need locally and then copy your files and db to the server as a zip.

Comment: Sound like a good idea. I will give it a try and reply you soon.

Comment: Do you know if there will be more issues like this which requires to use the command line in the future? I want to setup things right at the first place.   really hope this is the only issue :)

Comment: I just curious before i do it in my localhost, what is the point if i am able to run those command to change the apache setting to work in my localhost if the same command cannot be run in the server?

Comment: @bedum your server apache settings should be fine. what usually people have issue with is permissions, but if you copy your files over you don't need to generate them. make sure you put your app in production mode once live.

Answer (score 0):

Try Running them commands via Cron..

/opt/php56/bin/php /home/account/public_html/site/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy>> /home/account/public_html/site/var/log/depoly.log

Answer (score 0):

Initial setting-up of Magento installation can give you a really hard time. People say Magento CMS has a steep learning curve. Yep, it is steep, alright. However, worth the time, for it makes you think a lot.

Magento 2 requires 2MB of RAM, as a minimum. As a rule, Magento is considered "resource intensive CMS", so shared hosting is not recommended.

Deciding on the right hosting solution for a new Magento installation is critical, unless you don't mind the hassle of migrating your store later on. You have several options:

Cloud hosting: scalable, fast, expensive.
Dedicated hosting: fixed system resources, fast, expensive.
VPS hosting: fixed system resources, fast if configured well, good prices. 
Shared hosting: not a good option.

To execute commands on your VPS server, you use PuttY and set up SSH key, so that you don't have to write in your credentials every time.