# Magento 2 - No Theme after installation

Tags: magento2, installation, composer

I had "magento 2" installed with composer.
the installation is running correctly.
Now, when I look at the backend or the frontend no Theme appears.

What could be wrong?
I have also tried it with the WebWizzard. Since the same error occurs.

Maybe someone can help

Comment: Does you see login forms in admin

Answer (score 0):

You can run below command(s) to deploy theme static content.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the folder dev/tools/Magento/Tools/View and run this in the command line.

```
php deploy.php
```

Else you check these links

- [Magento 2 404 error for scripts and css](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64802/magento-2-404-error-for-scripts-and-css/64808)
- [CSS and Javascript files are not loading after Magento 2 installation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64857/css-and-javascript-files-are-not-loading-after-magento-2-installation/65192#65192)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to chown your files after you ran this as a root user.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/71883)

Comment: I meant Don't forget to

Answer (score 0):

**If you are facing theming issue after Installation in magento 2. You can follow these steps :**

1. **Run this query :**

> INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, value) VALUES ('dev/static/sign',
>   0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;

2. **For local machine run this query:**

> UPDATE  `<dbname>`.`core_config_data` SET  `value` =  '0' WHERE 
>   `core_config_data`.`path` LIKE  '%web/seo/use_rewrites%';

3. **Remove all the files from pub and var directory :**

> sudo rm -rf var/di var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/cache/
>   pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs/ 
>   pub/static/deployed_version.txt

4. **Give Permission to var and pub directories of your project :**

> sudo chmod -R 777 var/* pub/*

5. **Upgrade Setup :**

> sudo  bin/magento setup:upgrade

6. **Deploy content :**

> sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

After these steps, you will be able to see proper theme.

Answer (score 0):

***You can try Following ways***

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

*Now, Login into admin panel* & go to

*Content => Configuration(Under design section) => Select your theme as Global*.

*Now again run following command in Cli*

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmod 777 -R var/ pub/static/ generated/
```

***You can check "theme" table in db & also check parent id of your theme.***