# A fresh install magento2.1, error 404 not found

Tags: magento2, error, magento-2.1, 404, not-found

A fresh install Magento2.1, but there is *"404 not found"* error on every page except `index.php` and in backend.

Beside `index.php` page's layout is a mess.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had these problem in ubuntu. You may try out these steps.

For **front end**

Move to directory install magento2. Use command in terminal:

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`.

For **admin side**:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride  all
</Directory>`
```

was not present in the end of file /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf before `</VirtualHost>`. Also make sure that mod_rewrite is enable by entering command:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: or you may follow http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130785/magento-2-no-theme-after-installation/130790#130790