# Magento2 site is not loading properly

Tags: magento2, php, javascript, console

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q05dv.jpg]

1. I  have ***Magento2*** site. When I load first time in the browser it's not loading.
2. Complete and show javascript error in the console but when I refresh, it shows correct? What is the issue in ***Magento 2***

Comment: Can you provide the javascript error screenshot.

Comment: thank arjun please check now these error come when i upload site first time but when i refresh this error not come and site work properly

Comment: Are you facing these after 1st installation of magento2. The admin and frontend goes blank and shows error then follow this link and my answer over there http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130920/a-fresh-install-magento2-1-error-404-not-found/130923#130923

Comment: no no all is set it not first time it happen always when i run on new browser

Comment: you can try it by either updating the browser version. Before that try to clear your browser cache and magento cache.

Comment: it problem in all browser infact i check other browsers

Comment: @imtiaz have you fix this issue. i am facing same issue in ultimo theme

Answer (score 0):

Last error solution:-

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timepicker' of undefined

means that

```
$.ui
```

is undefined. So, you probably have not included `jQuery` UI.

Try to include it before any of your scripts (except `jQuery` itself).

Comment: ok but when i refresh its work

Comment: @Arjun I am facing same issue so where can i include jQuery file in my website?

Answer (score 0):

Have you written any custom javascript? As the answer answer states you have an issue with jqueryui. Although to explain further you shouldn't need to include jquery or jquery ui. Just use requirejs to load it for you. For example

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/accordion'
], function($) {
    $.widget('vendor.customAccordion', $.mage.accordion, {
        someAction: function(element) {
            // your code here
        }
    });
})
```

https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-use-jquery-and-requirejs-in-magento-2-javascript-solutions.html