# Magento 2 Cannot install sample data without blank pages or permission errors

Tags: magento2

I am on day 3 of trying to successfully install and use Magento 2 sample data.

The Magento installation goes fine but the trouble is all after installing the sample data.

This is what I'm doing:

```
1. Set the swap:

    /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
    /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
    /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
    sudo composer update

2. Set Developer Mode:

    sudo php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

3. Download Sample Data:

     sudo php bin/magento sampledata:deploy

4. Install Sample Data

After this I always get a blank page...

So I do this:

    sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
    sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
    sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
    sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
```

This I get lots of permission errors etc...

So I give up and start again.

Can anyone help on how to successfully do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Magento 2 installation steps**

First of all download Magento2 with sample data from https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

Then to install follow the steps in given links (because we are downloading zip so g to localhost lnk & directly start to install from steps 3 w.r.t. below link)

http://astrio.net/blog/magento-2-installation-local-server/

OR

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bd_wvYj_WzQ

Now we know that there are some problems after installation for that you can check my answer in below given link

[A fresh install magento2.1, error 404 not found](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130920/a-fresh-install-magento2-1-error-404-not-found/130923#130923)

If you still find some other kind of error google it or let me know may be i could help you.

For more error you can refer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLJhunAAcHI

Comment: I am using DigitalOcean where I use a script that installs Magento without the Sample data...I need instuctions for installing the sample data on an already installed instance of Magento 2

Comment: You're missing the `magento setup:upgrade` at the end. [Here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-composer.html) is documentation on how to install sample data after Magento has already been installed.