# CSS and JS not loading after installing Magento 2, setup:static-content:deploy shows error

Tags: magento2, error, installation, static-content

I have recently installed Magento2. CSS and JS not loading after installing Magento 2. I have used composer to install. This magento 2 files I have taken by a checkout from a live website.

Also the `php magento setup:static-content:deploy` command is not working. Running this command gives the following error:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/mongo.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mongo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 Could not open input file: magento
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS and Javascript files are not loading after Magento 2 installation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64857/css-and-javascript-files-are-not-loading-after-magento-2-installation)

Answer (score 0):

please run this command form command prompt

```
php magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

The following command deploys static content for the US English (en_US) language, excludes the Luma theme provided with Magento, and does not minify HTML files.

**generating static view files for one theme and one area**
The following command generates static view files for all languages, the frontend area only, the Magento Luma theme only, without generating fonts

for more info please visit :http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

Comment: I am getting this warning:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/mongo.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mongo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Could not open input file: magento

Comment: Please this command from your project root directory like : php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Yes, I did that only Navin

Comment: Please follow this may be help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565521/error-in-php5-unable-to-load-dynamic-library