# Css and Js are not loaded after install fresh Magento 2.1.3

Tags: magento2, csv, requirejs

I have installed Magento 2.1.3  after installation I go at admin but the admin link are not seeing proper I think some `CSS` and `JS` are missing ,

After I run deploy static command and re index and remove cache,

And then start admin panel but now its seeing weird

No `CSS` or `JS` file are loaded.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got same issue,

Perfect solutions reference are

[CSS and Javascript files are not loading after Magento 2 installation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64857/css-and-javascript-files-are-not-loading-after-magento-2-installation)

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue when i install magento in localhost, please try

> 1 Delete all folders in pub/static. Don't delete .htaccess and other files.
>
> 2 cd to the magento dir and then run
>
> 3 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> 4 php bin/magento indexer:reindex

if you can't deploy with low memory, please try

> php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have also got the same issue.

Fixed by

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and

```
service apache2 restart
```

Ref - [Magento 2 CSS and JavaScript not loading from correct folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder)