# Magento 2 1.0.0-beta creating a new vendor/theme from Magento/luma breaks FE

Tags: theme, magento2, css, bug, less-css

I created a new Vendor/theme where, in the theme.xml, i referenced the Magento/luma theme. As i understand it right, the fallback should now grap styles from the luma theme and my new theme should fully look like luma.

What actually happens is `CSS compilation from source variable @font-family-name__base is undefined in file` in pub static `styles-l.css` and `styles-m.css` after reload FE or even after `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`.
So it seems that the compilation is trying to use the right files but cannot process variables.

Is that a behavior which is already spottet somehow, did i something wrong?

Comment: Not spotted as far as I know. Worth [filing an issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues).

Comment: -> on windows it helps a lot to have a console with admin rights but does not solve the problem at all

Comment: i'll investigate a bit further but add it today, if i didn't found a solution

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the Problem was produced by trying to compile everything in a console without admin rights on win10.

So if you face such an issue, clean out the folders:

- static/frontend/Vendor
- var/view_preprocessed

and run `grund deploy` in console with admin rights.
It might come up that the JS and some other files cannot be found, in order to solve that issue check topic [Magento 2 404 error for scipts and css](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64802/magento-2-404-error-for-scipts-and-css/64808#64808).