# Desactivate Symlinks in Magento 2 for Docker

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to install a Magento 2 instance in a Docker context.
The problem is that symlinks are not allowed in this context.

Is there any alternative to symlinks ? Or maybe, is there a way to desactivate them ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why symlinks are not allowed?  Do you mean symlinks on static files?

Comment: First of all, Tanks for your answer.
Yes, this is for static files, for example  pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Reward/css/source/_module.less -> vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Reward/web/css/source/_module.less

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove 574 line from [di.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/etc/di.xml#L574) the copy strategy will be used.

See [Magento 2 404 error for scripts and css](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64802/magento-2-404-error-for-scipts-and-css) for details

Comment: I truly wish the actual line was on the answer