# Magento 2 local development environment

Tags: magento2, database, development, git, environment-emulation

I have always used MAMP PRO to configure my Magento sites for local dev, but with Magento 2 requiring mysql 5.6, I haven't had much luck setting up site successfully on local server with MAMP...plus I'm reading a lot that it's more or less abandonware.

I used this Vagrant setup: https://github.com/paliarush/magento2-vagrant-for-developers, which seemed to work alright, but not quite as intuitive to configure the host names and set up project.

Any other suggestions or ideas on some efficient/easy to set up local dev environment packages for Magento 2. Or is a VM my best bet?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows: [Uniform Server](http://www.uniformserver.com/) is an easy-to-use portable server (WAMP stack) that supports Magento 2 out-of-box. Current configuration includes MySQL 5.6 and PHP 7.0, although you can change to other versions via module installers if you'd prefer.

Note that Magento 2.0 still has trouble running on Windows natively in development mode, due to symlink issues. See https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/64808/1905 for a fix.

That being said, Vagrant is generally the recommended approach.

For Mac or Linux, you might be better off installing the AMP packages directly rather than trying to deal with MAMP, but Vagrant would probably be easier overall.

Comment: Sir...Can is expect good development speed of magento 2...if i use Vagrant on my window 7 ( i5+12Gb Ram). I can also upgrade to window 8 or 10 if its required but I want good speed in development which i am not getting now. Request you to provide suggestions.

Comment: I've tried dozens of servers and none of them worked on my computer(i5, 12GBRAM, SSD; Win8.1 + Ubuntu). All were extremely slow and produced server errors. I've just tried Uniform Server but it returns error 500 on `http://localhost/magento2/setup/index.php/landing-installer`

Answer (score 1):

If you want an all-purpose local development stack where you can choose from different PHP, MySQL and Web server versions and are also not afraid of using Docker, you could go for the **[devilbox](https://github.com/cytopia/devilbox)**.

> The devilbox is a modern and highly customisable dockerized PHP stack supporting full LAMP and MEAN and running on all major platforms. The main goal is to easily switch and combine any version required for local development. It supports an unlimited number of projects for which vhosts and DNS records are created automatically. Email catch-all and popular development tools will be at your service as well. Configuration is not necessary, as everything is pre-setup with mass virtual hosting.

Getting it up and running is pretty straight-forward:

```
# Get the devilbox
$ git clone https://github.com/cytopia/devilbox
$ cd devilbox

# Create docker-compose environment file
$ cp env-example .env

# Edit your configuration
$ vim .env

# Start all containers
$ docker-compose up
```

[image: devilbox]

**Links:**

- Github: https://github.com/cytopia/devilbox
- Website: http://devilbox.org

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to update MySQL to 5.6 on your MAMP install, MAMP has a simple script that does the upgrade for you. I have used it to get a local dev site for Magento 2. I did run into some issues with trying to get a upgrade script to run in module I was working on, and I never went back to de-bug it. But this is a short term solution till you find another dev environment you like better.

[MAMP MySQL Upgrade](http://blog-en.mamp.info/2015/07/how-to-use-mysql-5-6-with-mamp-and-mamp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is most popular tools workflows to run Magento 2 locally:

- Official Magento DevBox (Beta) -
  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/docker/docker-over.html
  , https://github.com/magento/magento2devbox-web
- Vagrant Box for Magento 2 Developers - https://github.com/paliarush/magento2-vagrant-for-developers