# Magento 2 - Setup page not displaying correctly

Tags: magento2, 404-page, setup

I am trying to install a magento 2 on an OVH shared hosting with a private sql server. I copied a magento 2 new package and I am currently encountering the following error when trying to launch the setup :

```
http://xxxxxx/setup/index.php/navigation Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://xxxxxx/setup/index.php/navigation/side-menu Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://xxxxxx/setup/index.php/navigation/header-bar Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Then after some time waiting on the page i get this :

```
angular.js:7715 POST http://xxxxxx/setup/index.php/session/prolong 404 (Not Found)
```

The setup works fine in local, what should I do ?

It isn't a Symlink error, I already modified the "virtualType name="developerMaterialization" section, and deleted files under pub/static.

My errors are angular.js errors.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 404 error for scripts and css](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64802/magento-2-404-error-for-scripts-and-css)

Comment: No, this is a different error and the fixes of your topic didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you check if file permissions are as recommended? Looks like setup folder is not readable by webuser.

Comment: I changed file permissions as recommended and it is still not working.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated please

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2504#issuecomment-159663316 Have you tried this?

Comment: Facing the same issue.. Bt unable to fix this.. what can be the solution for this

Answer (score 10):

I fix this by the https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2504#issuecomment-159663316

Here is the code

1. My nginx site config

   ```
   upstream fastcgi_backend {
       server unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
   }

   server {
       listen 80;
       server_name YOUR_IP_OR_DOMAIN_NAME;
       set $MAGE_ROOT YOUR_MAGENTO_FILE_PATH;
       set $MAGE_MODE developer;
       include YOUR_MAGENTO_FILE_PATH/nginx.conf.sample;
   }
   ```

2.Modify the `nginx.conf.sample` file

```
    location /setup {
        root $MAGE_ROOT;

        location ~ ^/setup/index.php {

            ### This fixes the problem:
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
            ################################

            fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

    }
```

3. Open th url in the browser

   http://YOUR_IP_OR_DOMAIN_NAME/setup

Comment: Hi, Wen Wei, I tried using your solution. and it worked perfectly in my Magento 2.1.8 using nginx. Thanks again

Comment: This is the problem. I wonder what a buggy thing.

Comment: Restart nginx after making this change. `sudo service nginx restart`

Answer (score 0):

I understand your situation so here is my solution form magento installation virtualhost for nginx.

1. Just u have to change php-fpm address according to your configuration
2. Set mage_root according to your magento installation folder.
3. Comment the cgi.fix_pathinfo=0  by ;cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
4. Also php-fpm config file **www.conf** must have user nginx like 
   user = nginx

   group = nginx

   listen.owner = nginx

   listen.group = nginx

   listen.mode = 0660
5. You php session dir must have ownership of nginx.
6. Here is Nginx VirtualHost Configuration file for magento2:> If u dont understand download this clean text file from this link....
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MI0JKx5Gx_dLFz2c6fyubgpSmM_TESux/view?usp=sharing
   [Download VirtualHost file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MI0JKx5Gx_dLFz2c6fyubgpSmM_TESux/view?usp=sharing)