# Magento 2 setup 503

Tags: magento2, installation, setup

Trying to install Magento 2 on a shared hosting platform

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
git clone https://github.com/magento/magento2.git
php composer.phar install
```

Go to http://example.com/setup and get a 503 Service Unavailable.

When I go to the logs I can see it states

```
File not found [/home/example/public_html/setup/index.php/session/prolong]
```

Any one know how to fix it?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114744/magento-2-setup-page-not-displaying-correctly

Comment: I did try this but unfortunately still no luck