# Magento 2 admin and customer login not working after clean installation

Tags: magento2

After a clean Magento 2 installation it does not allow me to login to the admin area nor sign into the shop as a customer.
When im trying to login to the admin panel it doesn't show any errors, but it look like it just reloads the login page. Either no error is shown when I fill in the wrong credentials.

I'm running:

- CentOS 6
- Apache/2.4.18
- PHP 5.6.22
- PHP handler: Suphp
- SuExec: Off

These are the cookies that are written after I tried to login:

[image: These are the cookies that are written]

By the way, im not running on localhost but a fqdn. I tried this already: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/64808/594 but no luck.

Anybody has a clue?

Comment: I too have a same problem. Have you fixed the issue?

Comment: I have the issue on localhost on Windows 10 :/