# Submenus NOT working in Magento 2 Admin>Configuration Panels

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration, stores

Does anyone know how to fix a brand new fresh install of Magento 2.1 when instantly upon installing NONE of the panels are expanding in Admin System Configuration??
Kinda hard to set up a store when a fresh new install has an immediate problem that doesn't even allow setup.

Answer (score 0):

run this command i think its working for you

**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

**php bin/magento cache:flush**

**php bin/magento indexer:reindex**

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

or

When not in production mode Magento 2 will try to create symlinks for some static resources. You can change that behavior by doing the following.

Open  **app/etc/di.xml** and find the **virtualType name="developerMaterialization"** section. In that section you'll find an item **name="view_preprocessed"** . You can modify it by changing the contents from **Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink** to **Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy**

after that Delete the files under **pub/static** to get read of any existing symlinks. You may want to be careful not to delete the **.htaccess** file.

The following is taken from https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/64808/594

Comment: Sorry, that did nothing for me.  I don't see anywhere on here to add a screenshot of what I'm talking about. But I've seen a lot of people offer this step you provided.  I think everybody else I've seen on the web, is not understanding what menus I'm talking about.  How can I get a screenshot posted on here?

Comment: sorry you couldn't post any screenshot because  you have less than 10 reputation .Please clarify what actually happen in admin

Comment: Ahh.  Well, when you go to Stores>Configuration, by default, the store view is Default Configuration.
The left column is full of tabs..ie. General, Catalog, Customers, etc.. And each of those tabs have their owns settings that display in the right column.
Well, my problem is that none of those tabs expand (Catalog, Customers, etc.)  So other than the very first 5 settings (Country Options, State Options, Locale Options, Store Information & Single Store Mode) I am unable to fully configure my store.