# Static resources cause 404 errors (Magento 2.1.5)

Tags: magento2, 404

I have a Magento 2.1.5 installation running, but it only works if I change my document root to `/pub`. If I don't, I get a *bunch* of 404 errors:

[image]

The problem is that eventually I'll have to move the installation to a hosting provider where the document root cannot be changed.

Only a folder called `_requirejs` is created within the `static` folder. There's no `version1492703026` anywhere to be found:

[image]

I've tried the following:

- Modify `di.xml` as per [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64802/magento-2-404-error-for-scripts-and-css)
- (Re)deploy all static content via the command-line
- Rewrite everything to `/pub`
- Restore the `.htaccess` files within the web root and `/pub`

Would anybody have any idea what's going on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `Sign Static Files` set to `Yes` in your configuration.

You can turn it off from admin panel. Go to

> Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Static Files
>   Settings

Or you can insert into `core_config_data` table new setting for path = `dev/static/sign` and value = `0`

Then run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and you clear your cache.

Answer (score 0):

Please do this process.

- Remove the folders(Not Files) from var
- Remove the folders(Not Files) from pub/static
- Now run this 4 command in this sequence
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
- php bin/magento indexer:reindex
- php bin/magento cache:flush

And after that it is not work then please give 777 permission to var and pub folder which are in the root directory.