# Unable to open admin page

Tags: admin, magento2.2.0

I have installed fresh copy of magento2.2.0. As I click on opening the magento2 admin page

```
[![Not Found

The requested URL /magento2/admin_12o514/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.][1]][1]
```

Comment: Try granting 777 permissions to var and pub folders.

Comment: I have already given 777 to var, pub, generated folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is solved with the help of [Magento 2 404 error for scripts and css](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64802/magento-2-404-error-for-scripts-and-css/64808#64808)

1. Open up app/etc/di.xml and find the `virtualType name="developerMaterialization"` section. You can modify it by changing the contents from
   `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink` to 
   `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

   Delete the files under `pub/static` to get rid of any existing symlinks.
2. You may want to be careful not to delete the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the mod_rewrite is active on your server or the file .htaccess doesn't exist.

Comment: .htaccess do exist

Comment: also tried the sudo a2enmod rewrite and restarted the apache/2.2.12 still getting the same error