# TypeError: require.config is not a function in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, error, requirejs, frontend-error, requirejs-config.js

Js, CSS is not loading properly. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by running:

```sh
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I got this error

Comment: Too many arguments, expected arguments "command".

Answer (score 3):

Please check mod_rewrite enabled in your server and also check the directory symlinks like this in your server.

```
Open /etc/apache2/apache2.conf 

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Is /var/www/ need to be included?

Comment: your using windows right..find the keyword like FollowSymlinks and give granted access.

Comment: Yes, it is windows 10. I put like this <Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory> but not working. It still shows the same thing.

Comment: mod rewrite enabled or not??

Comment: Yes, I enabled it already. Actually, my other Magento project working well. But this one I copied from a friend not loading CSS, js.

Answer (score 2):

please check it pub/static/ inside htaccess exits or not same path pub/media/ inside check it after all command apply it

Comment: htaccess exists in both folders.

Comment: change to other default magento htaccess use it  on same path after cache clean and flush

Comment: please ip define in your url change to admin side core_config_data inside

Comment: admin page showing page not found like that.

Comment: please try to all command

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/163096)

Comment: @ManashviBirla I am trying but if not changes work on it so i say to revert it code

Comment: Actually, my other Magento project working well. But this one I copied from a friend not loading CSS, js.

Comment: may be some issue proper command not working

Answer (score 1):

This could be an issue with symlinks.  I see that deploy.php worked for you, but you may also try `deleting the resources` from `pub/static` and seeing if the instructions from https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/64808/594 work for you.  If so, then it may save you some time during development as it should be faster than running deploy.php.

**I hope this will help**

Comment: I followed those steps perfectly but it is not working. And admin page showing page not found like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you imported database from the server where secure connection (https) is enabled, you need to disable it in local copy of the database (because you probably doesn't have secure connection on a localhost):

```
bin/magento setup:store-config:set --use-secure=0 --use-secure-admin=0
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is any speed optimizer modules. I didn't notice my client had one called MagePow Speedoptimizer and it sneakily was moving the require.js from loading in the head section to the body which doesn't work well at all, so I disabled it.

There are other speedoptimizer modules too for Magento 2 that can cause this.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the many reason for the same error.

In my case my base url was set as http but it will redirects to https protocol.

I have set https protocol in base url and it works.