# Refused to apply style from magento2

Tags: magento2

`Magento 2`

After installing `payment-module`. running these command lines caused the error of files not found from the **`pub/static/version******/adminhtml/`**

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade;
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy;
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean;

Comment: please do php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: i did php bin/magento setup:di:compile.

This page isn’t working 
localhost redirected you too many times.

Comment: I found the solution here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64802/magento-2-404-error-for-scripts-and-css