# Magento 2 Trying to switch from Developer to Production breaking website

Tags: magento2

My website is working just fine on Developer mode, whenever I try to switch to Production my website is not loading js or icons/images. I am attaching an image so you can see the errors in chrome devtools. In addition I am following the guideline from here: [Set the Magento mode](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html) I have not deleted the .htaccess file. I've tried to follow this [Magento 2 issues](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64802/magento-2-404-error-for-scripts-and-css/64808#64808) with no success again.

[image: Error logs]

Comment: Have you got the message that static content was successfully deployed after switching to production mode? Try running `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento 2, You do not need to run `static:content:deploy` command every time when your Magento mode is `default` or `developer`, but when you change Magento mode to `production` at that time Magento will not generate static content file automatically.

So you need to run deploy commands in this sequence..

You can change your Magento mode from `developer` to `production` using below command.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation
```

After running above command your Magento mode will be change from `developer` to `production`, then you need to run below commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US bg_BG
```

Here I've used `bg_BG` in `setup:static-content:deploy` command that is your locale which you have set for **Bulgarian** country. If you will run only this command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` at that time you can see Magento will generate files under `en_US` locale by default in following directory.

> pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Theme/en_US/

And your locale is `bg_BG` so you need to generate files for that locale. So you need to run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US bg_BG
```

When you run above command at that time Magento will generate files under `en_US` and `bg_BG` as well.

> pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Theme/en_US/
>
> pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Theme/bg_BG/

Hope this information helps you!

Comment: Let me know if it helps. Thanks

Comment: Perfect worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please follow any of below Solutions:

**1)** Your issue will solved by running below command, if not then follow below mentioned steps:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US be_Bg
```

**2)** when you switch dev to production mode, remove cache, generated and pub/static.

**3)** Run Below mentioned commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US be_Bg
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope any of above solution will help.