# Problems after installation

Tags: magento-2.0, admin-panel

After installing Magento 2, I can't access the administrator page it shows 404 error, see screenshot:

[image: 404 error]

Comment: try this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96289/no-images-or-js-on-new-magento-2-installation/96291#96291

Comment: The screenshot shows a broken frontend home page, no 404 error. Are you asking two questions at once? What is the URL you use to access the admin panel? Also relevant for the broken frontend issue: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48256/magento-2-installation-css-js-images-not-loading

Comment: This question was asked plenty of time! Please make a search to the community before ask any question.

Answer (score 0):

Refer my question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121312/magento-2-shows-404-error-and-front-end-css-crashed).
Steps to solve this.

1. You need to `enable module rewrite in server`.(If you don't know refer [this](http://velanapps.com/install-magento-2-in-wamp-server/))

Run in CLI

2. To deploy content:
   `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
3. To flush cache:
   `php bin/magento cache:flush`
4. To Reindex data:
   `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Now check your both frontend and admin.